# Unable to get Apache docker container to serve virtual host with subdomain

Tags: apache, docker

I have a site I currently run that works well, but both to learn and to make it more portable, I've been trying to dockerize it. I'm using the offical apache and php images, and setup my virtual hosts identical to how I have on the running site, just with different domains. Unfortunately, while I can get one to work, the second does not.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api.gamersplane.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/api

    ErrorLog "/var/log/gamersplane.api"
    CustomLog "/var/log/gamersplane.api" common

    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://api:9000/var/www/$1
    ProxyPassReverse ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://api:9000/var/www/$1

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule !\.(css|jpg|js|gif|png|ico|eot|woff|ttff|svg|psd)$ dispatch.php

    <Directory /var/www/api/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    LogLevel notice
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ErrorLog "/var/log/gamersplane"
    CustomLog "/var/log/gamersplane" common

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://api:9000/var/www/$1
    ProxyPassReverse ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://api:9000/var/www/$1

    ServerName gamersplane.local
    ServerAlias *.gamersplane.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule !\.(css|jpg|js|gif|png|ico|eot|woff|ttff|svg|psd)$ dispatch.php

    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    LogLevel notice
</VirtualHost>
```

Originally, I had the first vhost (api.gamersplane) second, but thought maybe it was the server alias that was the problem. Then I switched positions, and even commented out the base (gamersplane.local), but had no luck. This works on the running site, so I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

Checking the headers returned by Postman, I do see it has the Apache and PHP headers, so it seems to be hitting SOMETHING, I just don't know what.

Comment: I am not sure you can use wildcard on ServerAlias

Comment: It works in production (a non-docker env). But even if I comment out that virtual host, the other one doesn't work.

Comment: Add serveralias. But as normal host name (can be the same as servername)